# bcp.exe in error

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

I'm getting the following error doing bcp in:

```
#@ Row 1: CTLIB Message:  - L0/O0/S0/N0/0/0:
blk_rowxfer(): blk layer: internal BLK-Library error: No value or default value available and NULL not allowed.  col = 19 @#
#@ Row 1: Not transferred @#
2012-01-31 11:24:27 AM      201112      1       ASSET SWAP CGD (PTCG16OM0004)       9961500     104158.1743509      119789.165823456        15630.9914725559        10000000        440001251       -104267.3350867     -102094.0679096     2173.2671771        15630.9914725559        2173.2671771        17804.2586496559        0.852281316158969       NULL
```

The problem is that the 19th column is identity and I don't have it in the file. In order to solve this I used the `bcp -N option`.

My command is this:

```
bcp.exe tablename in filein -N -c -t \t\t -r \n -U user -P pass -S server -e errorFile
```

---

And the most weird is that it works in one machine, but not in another.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of this was the problem:

1. Sybase Version in remote machine was 12.5 (in local machine was 15.0)
2. BCP in file had NULL instead of nothing (blank) when representing NULL in database